# Unable to execute sample axis2Client WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to use sample Axis2Client but I am facing an issue as below. I am following the page https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Using+the+ESB+as+JMS+Consumer+and+Producer.

```
ant stockquote -Dmode=placeorder -Dtrpurl="jms:/StockQuoteProxy?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=Content-Type&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"
Buildfile: /Users/user/WUM/wso2ei-6.6.0/samples/axis2Client/build.xml

init:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/WUM/wso2ei-6.6.0/samples/axis2Client/build.xml:307: /Users/user/WUM/wso2ei-6.6.0/wso2/lib/endorsed does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please remove the following from the build.xml located in wso2ei-6.6.0/samples/axis2Client. Then try executing the same command again

```
        <fileset dir="../../wso2/lib/endorsed">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
```

Comment: It worked for me as well. What actually those files do and why are they missing?